# Don't stage or commit submodules (nested Git repositories)

Tags: git

I `git clone`'d two projects. Say they're project A and B. I then add them to `.gitignore`:

```
projectA
projectB
```

And they disappear from Git status. But when I do `git add .`, I see `new file: projectA` and `new file: projectB`. Git then adds them as submodules. I just want them to be regular untracked directories. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

To untrack any directory without actually deleting the directory itself, you must

```
git rm -r --cached <your directory>
```

1. Remove all the files in the directory.
2. Remove the files from the git index (not delete them)

all files in your directory (that you don't want to track) will be removed with the help of option `-r`

removing the files in the directory only from the git index and not the working copy is done with the help of the option `--cached`